# How do I design a maids and cleaning website website with CRM software integrated?

Tags: crm

Please I am a novice and want to start a project on Maids and Cleaning website with CRM to manage clients, employee payroll and other features. But I don't know where to start, like what Language tools is easier and secure I can easily use to handle this project. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read tour and how to ask - this probably belongs at some discord or discussion group rather than here.  https://stackoverflow.com/tour  and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask